# I get RecycleView in Fragment and after click on recycleview element i need to send data to this fragment and restart it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Hi i have recycleView in my fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_petrole, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
    allPetroles = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("petroles");

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(allPetroles, getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    return view;
}
```

In RecycleView adapter i set OnClickListener in onBindViewHolder, so i need after click on some raw sent back to Fragment some info(position) and then make some changes(resent this info to Activity and add some new view there on Gmaps)
This onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.linearClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            positionClick = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();


--------------I NEED CODE HERE----------------------

        }
    });
    if (positionClick == position) {
        holder.linearClick.setSelected(true);
    }
    else {
        holder.linearClick.setSelected(false);
    }
```

and i don't understand how i should this do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RecyclerAdapter :

1- add an Inner Interface :

```
/**********
 *
 *  Inner interface
 *
 */
public interface OnClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(Item item);
}
```

2- Add a parameter in the constructor :

```
public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Item> data, OnClickListener onClickListener) { 
    mContext = context;
    mData = data;
    mListener = onClickListener 
}
```

3- Call the listener :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.linearClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //positionClick = position;
            //you don't need this here : notifyDataSetChanged();
            mListener.onItemClicked(mData.get(position));
        }
    });
    if (positionClick == position) {
        holder.linearClick.setSelected(true);
    }
    else {
        holder.linearClick.setSelected(false);
    }
```

Your Fragment should implements `RecyclerAdapter.OnClickListener`

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerAdapter.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_petrole, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
        allPetroles = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("petroles");

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), allPetroles, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    void onItemClicked(Item item) {
        // TODO put your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i don't understant what
 mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), allPetroles, this);

here i need the clicklistener object but i don't understant which one? this recycleview is creates from this fragment

Comment: This is your fragment that implements the listener

Comment: The adapter of the RecycleView is - 

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Item> data, OnClickListener onClickListener) { 
    mContext = context;
    mData = data;
    mListener = onClickListener 
}

and i create this adapter in my fragment, in your code 
mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), allPetroles, this);
we haven't last argument(clickListener object)

Comment: In Fragment : new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), allPetroles, this) ===> there is 3 arguments so i don't understand your comment

Comment: sorry, it's my fault. I Inattentively compared your code and mine. Your help is good, thanks